# Награда за вручение награды

Tags: предложение, конкурс

Почему бы не дать какой-то бонус тому, кто присуждает вознаграждение конкретному ответу?

Некоторым бывает всё равно, кому награда улетит автоматически.

Однако, если сделать, что N% стоимости возвращалось тому кто её объявил, то награды вручали бы активнее.

Comment: Тогда это все равно, что объявлять награду на N% меньше.

Comment: A бонус есть — знаки.

Answer (score -3):

Хорошо, рассмотрим все варианты(вероятности - мои предположения):

1. Автор не нашел решения.
   Значит ему выгодно принять вообще любой ответ. Отсюда два пути:

   1. Он бездумно принимает любой ответ(невероятно низкая доля вероятности).
      Отсюда еще два пути:

      1. принят самый залайканный ответ(высокая доля вероятности)
      2. принят любой кроме залайканного ответа(крайне низкая доля вероятности).
   2. Он разумно принимает ответ(наиболее близкий к истине)(средняя доля вероятности).
   3. Не предпринимает никаких действий(средняя доля вероятности).
2. Автор нашел решение. Отсюда два пути:

   1. Он принимает ответ(высокая доля вероятности)
   2. Он не принимает ответ(низкая доля вероятности)

Это система, которая действует сейчас.
При принятии изменений, которые вы предлагаете внести, сильно увеличатся 1.1 и 1.2 (в том же отношении, что и прежде(новый 1.1 / новый 1.2 = старый 1.1 / старый 1.2), что практически исключит 1.3, сильно уменьшится 2.2.

Основываясь на этих данных, можно сказать, что принятие вашей системы будет весьма полезным шагом - 1.1.2 в абсолютном отношении увеличится ненамного. А это единственный негативный момент в этой системе.